# Multi Step Forms con Pagina Maestra y Web Forms ASP.NET C#

Tags: html, c#, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

Buenas a todos comunidad les pido de su ayuda para poder resolver mi problema. Cualquier ayuda sera muy bien recibida y de antemano muchas gracias.

Tengo en mi pagina maestra el diseño de los pasos en este caso son los círculos que se muestran en la imagen encerrados en el rectángulo azul. En mis WebForms solo tengo los textbox para introducir los datos y guardarlos en la base de datos.

Sin mas mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Como puedo acceder a los círculos desde un formulario para que cuando le de en guardar se cambie a una imagen de color verde y me pase a otro formulario cambiando la imagen a color naranja?. Tomando en cuanta que cada paso es un nuevo formulario WebForm y no un panel.

Gracias por su ayuda.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Epj5.png

Comment: Porque los circulos en una Master Page? eso no esta bueno, entiendo quieres realizar un wizard, donde puedas ir avanzando y tomando los datos de cada step.  Encapsulas ese circulos en un componente, puede ser un User Control, y lo pones en cada pagina, indicando que circulo debe cambiar de color segun en que pagina lo ubiques, entonces cuando navegues el componente tomara el colo que le corresponde a esa pagina

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Leandro lo haré como me indicas y les cuento como me va con esto.

Answer (score 0):

No se usa la `master page` para esto que estas planteando

Recomendaria que utilizaras el componente `Wizard` de asp.net para implementar la serie de pasos donde capturas los datos

[Wizard Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard?view=netframework-3.5)

Este componente lo encontraras en la toolbox del visual studio

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" >  
    <HeaderStyle ... />  
    <NavigationButtonStyle ... />  
    <SideBarButtonStyle ... />  
    <SideBarStyle ... />  
    <WizardSteps>  
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Student Details">  

            //contenido

        </asp:WizardStep>  
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Student Course Details">  

            //contenido

        </asp:WizardStep>  
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep3" runat="server" Title="Student Personal Details">  

         //contenido

        </asp:WizardStep>  

         <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep4" runat="server" Title="Student Summary">  

            //contenido

        </asp:WizardStep>  


    </WizardSteps>  

</asp:Wizard>
```

observaras que se puede definir el template del `HeaderStyle` y tambien el

[Wizard.HeaderTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.headertemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

es alli donde defines el html de como sera el header del wizard

[Wizard Control In ASP.NET Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-wizard-control-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp/)

Comment: Que tal Leandro así es podría haber usado un Wizard pero no lo hice ya que mis formularios contienen mucha información y por eso decidí ponerlos en un Web Form ya que por cada paso un usuario es dueño de ese formulario y de ese paso y cada que entra al sitio(con Autenticacion de Windows) el puede ver en que paso se encuentra el proceso. Es por ello que decido ponerlos en una pagina maestra. 

Entonces vuelvo a plantear la pregunta.

¿Como puedo acceder a mis círculos para cambiarle la imagen cada que un usuario autenticado (por medio de windows) ha completado su proceso?

Gracias.

Comment: no aplicar el wizard por el hecho que tengan mucha informacion es correcto ya que deberias tener todo el diseño en una sola pagina, ahora por el tema de seguridad no deberias tener problema ya que segun el perfil del usuario debajas acceder a detemrinado step o no, o cargas la pagina mostrandole un determinado step en concreto, eo se puede definir desde codigo cuando cargas la pagina

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Leandro te agradezco por tu ayuda.